# Сan we get number of available developer sandboxes in production via apex

Tags: apex, sandbox, tooling-api

I need to get number of **available Developer Sandboxes** in production via apex.
I know that we can get it via Setup :
[image]

I know that we can get number of Developer Sandboxes which we use via Tooling Api and [Sandbox Info](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm).

Then depends on Organization Edition get number of Sandboxes Available Per Edition from here  [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) .

[image]
And calculate differense in Apex Code.

However we also can contact Salesforce Support and get additional Developer Sandboxes license :

> You can buy additional Developer Pro sandboxes for any edition, or Partial and Full sandboxes for Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance editions.
> Developer Sandboxes aren’t available for purchase but are bundled with add-on sandboxes of other types.

So Is there a way to get number of **available Developer Sandboxes** in production via **apex**

*Any help will be appreciated.

thank you*

Comment: As an idea only -- `PageReference page = new PageReference('/07E');
System.debug(page.getContent().toString());`
Pay attention to Language and this can be probably disabled in  any moment (getContent for setup pages)

Comment: @kurunve Thank you a lot.  
I understand that it can be disabled, However it works for me now.